# i want to have different views in rows of listview in android

Tags: android, listview

[image]

I want to show the different view in single listview as shown in the images ... how it can be possible to do this 
i have tried using two listview with different Adapter but that suits to our requirement

Comment: thanks for the quick response but i have gone through this example but my requirement is different as i need to show two different rows in single list view .... how that can be possilbe

Comment: if you know your row is 2 then better to use other widgets like Textview

Comment: post what you have tried so far..and more description

Comment: in one row it has two textview but in other row we have around 12 textview and 2 imageview ... how to do that ??

Comment: what you trying to display??and from where you trying to display??

Comment: how can i show 2 adapter in single listview ...can u tell me that

Comment: see here https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge

Comment: you can user recyclerview for this..it will be easy...http://arjunu.com/2015/10/android-recyclerview-with-different-cardviews/

Comment: @mike can u give me some example to do this

Comment: @hetal can u give me some example for tut ??

Comment: i dont want to use the lib ??

Comment: sure...with recyclerview?

Comment: @hetal can u give me some example which show different row

Answer (score -1):

You should use the `getViewTypeCount()` method:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getViewTypeCount()

This way you will be able to use `getItemViewType(int)` to know which layout you should use:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)

Answer (score -1):

first create two xlm file for your different layout...then in adapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

   @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return 2;
        }

   @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return list.get(position).getType();        }
}
 @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   int listViewItemType = getItemViewType(position);

   if (listViewItemType == 1) {
                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.type_even, null);
                } 
            else{ 
                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.type_odd, null);
                }
}
```

you can change this as per your requirement....if you have any question then feel free to ask

Comment: return list.get(position).getType();   can u explain this line of code

Comment: in your list where you pass data...also pass type of view like 1 or 2 or what ever you want

Comment: by passing view type with data you can get idea about which row is using which layout